# DateTime.Min Value when string equals EmptyOr Null in Linq to XML

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am attempting to parse an xml string that has dates in there.  The object that I am trying to fill has a nullable DateTime.  But if the string that I pull back has an empty value, I want it to be the min Date Value.  and I want to assign that to the variable?  Is there a simple way to do that using LINQ

```
 IEnumerable<PatientClass> template = (IEnumerable<PatientClass>)(from templates in xDocument.Descendants("dataTemplateSpecification")//elem.XPathSelectElements(string.Format("//templates/template[./elements/element[@name=\"PopulationPatientID\"and @value='{0}' and @enc='{1}']]", "1", 0))
                                               select new PatientClass
                                               {
 PCPAppointmentDateTime = DateTime.Parse(templates.Descendants("element").SingleOrDefault(el => el.Attribute("name").Value == "PCPAppointmentDateTime").Attribute("value").Value),
 });
```

The object that I am using is this...

```
 class PatientClass
 { 
   public DateTime? PCPAppointmentDateTime { get; set; }
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use null rather than a magic value?

Comment: Out of interest, why would you use `DateTime.MinValue` when you have null available? Why bother having it nullable to start with if you're never going to use the null value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should wrap `Parse` in a method. Return a `DateTime`.

```
DateTime ValueOrMin(string value)
{
     if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) return DateTime.MinValue;
     return DateTime.Parse(value);
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  I might end up doing this.  I would have figured this would have been a common enough problem that there was already some functionality inherent in Linq itself.  But Thanks for the help and advice everyone.

Answer (score 2):

There’s no "simple" way other than the obvious approach, which isn’t that complicated either:

```
var dateString = templates.Descendants("element")
      .SingleOrDefault(el => el.Attribute("name").Value == "PCPAppointmentDateTime")
      .Attribute("value").Value;
PCPAppointmentDateTime = dateString == ""
      ? DateTime.MinValue
      : DateTime.Parse(dateString);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void DoWhatever(){
     PCPAppointmentDateTime = ParseDate(templates.Descendants("element").SingleOrDefault(el => el.Attribute("name").Value == "PCPAppointmentDateTime").Attribute("value").Value);
}

private DateTime ParseDate(string dateString){
    DateTime date;
    if (DateTime.TryParse(dateString, out date))
         return date;
    return DateTime.MinValue;
}
```